# Fade in Image Radially from Middle to Edges with TweenLite

Tags: javascript, html, css, gsap

I have an image, see below: [image]

that I would like to position absolute on my page with the following css:

```
.bg-slide21-layer-3 {
    background-image: url('/images/slide21/bg_layer3.png');
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: none;
    height: 46vh;
    width: 78.5vw;
    z-index: -8;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0vw;
    right: 0;
    left: -0.5vw;
    opacity: 1;
 }
```

I would like to use Tween to make it start at opacity 0, and animate itself onto the page from the inside (where the dots are) to the edges. I don't know how to do this. I cannot find an ease in that works radially.

Intuitively, I have tried to add a cover to the element so the HTML is as follows:

```
<div class='bg-slide21-layer-3-cover'>
    <div class='bg-slide21-layer-3'></div>
</div>
```

with the cover CSS as follows:

```
.bg-slide21-layer-3-cover {
    width: 10%;
    height: 10%;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -5;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

and use this sort of Tween:

```
TweenMax.to(
        $('.bg-slide21-layer-3-cover'), 
        2, 
        { opacity: 1, width: "100vw", height: "100vh", ease:Power1.easeNone }
    );
```

with the intention of making the small div in the middle expand outwards. However, this doesn't work, because my inner image (.bg-slide21-layer-3) is absolutely positioned relative to the cover div in the middle, so the effect just looks like its fading in from the left-bottom corner.

Does anyone know how to properly do this? How would I position the inner div relative to the body rather than the cover div so that as the cover increases in size, it looks like the image is fading in from the middle out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a round box and rescale it

```css
div {
  position:relative;
  background-repeat: none;
  height: 46vh;
  width: 78.5vh;
  overflow:hidden;
  border:solid;
}
div:before {
  position:absolute;
  content:'';
  display:block;
  height:25%;
  width:15%;
  top:70%;
  left:57%;
 background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhs0G.png);
  background-size: 650% 400%;
  background-position: 67% 93%;
  transition:1s linear;
  border-radius:100%;
  
}
div:hover:before {
  background-size:100% 100%;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0
}
body {background:linear-gradient(to top left, lightgray, white,gray);
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is that there are other background layers underneath it, so a gradient would cover all of them?

Comment: it might,be possible not  if each bg are in the same element and only the mask rescaled via background-size. bg to see always will require to be first and translucide to show pins and gradient. what do you really have ? opacity was also an hint. else use an svg

Comment: I have 4 separate divs. They are not contained inside the same element (other than body). The cover element in my description is one of those 4.

I'm not sure what you mean about using opacity? How would I do it? Is there any way to do it by making the cover div start from the middle and expand outwards? Its just, in this case I need the lines div inside to be positioned relative to the body, not the inner element..

Comment: okay, in this case my approach and ideas are totally useless :( i'll propose something else

Comment: @user1934426 another idea is a round box resized via height/width and a reset on  coordonates,  bg-position & bg size. updated answer's snippet.

Comment: Thank you for your help, let me try this out.

Comment: I tried it, but I need the div to be positioned absolute...I can't seem to get it to look like its being drawn like in the example you've shown.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141570/discussion-between-user1934426-and-gcyrillus).